# uso obrigatório de uma palavra em um formulário html

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um input onde o usuário digitara um titulo, preciso que esse titulo tenha acrescido (blog) ao seu final.

exemplo: meu titulo (blog) ou seu titulo blog

se ele não colocar, preciso acrescentar isso automaticamente ou impedir o envio do formulário com javascript ou outra linguagem.

- o software usa php, é um wep app, o titulo será salvo em banco de dados.

Comment: Se vc considera a possibilidade de acrescentar isso automaticamente, você pode desonerar o usuário dessa obrigação e acrescentar no próprio PHP antes de gravar no banco. Algo do tipo: `$titulo .= ' blog';`

Comment: como faria no laravel?  eu estava considerando usar um formulário html, nesse caso eu teria que pegar o valor exato do campo na validação para então acrescentar a tag (blog).

Comment: Não sei nada de Laravel :/

Comment: tranquilo, php dá certo também, eu do um jeito aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, podemos facilitar as coisas usando javascript, por exemplo, você pode checar se o valor existe, se existir, deixar passar, caso contrário, acrescentar, é uma boa?
Para checar usando o javascript podemos usar o `string.indexOf("blog") != -1` caso não contenha "blog" na string, ele retorna -1, caso contenha, ela retorna a posição da string.

Caso esteja utilizando um input, podemos pegar o valor e checar a cada letra digitada, podemos disparar uma função a cada letra digitada acrescentando a tag `onkeyup` por exemplo, onde checaríamos letra a letra.

Exemplo para checagem, lembrando que uso [jquery](https://jquery.com/) para pegar o valor:

```
<input type="text" id="texto" onkeyup="checar()">

<script type="text/javascript">
  function checar(){
    if($("#texto").val().indexOf("blog") != -1){return true;}
  }
</script>
```

Podemos checar no ato de envio do formulário, e assim, acrescentar na string.

Comment: boa, tem problema ser com jquery não, estou usando bootstrap no formulário.

Comment: Pronto, vai ser fácil fazer a checagem então, pode até fazer essa substituição nessa própria função

Comment: Não precisa de `else`, porque se entrar no `if` nem vai chegar no `return false`.

Comment: Verdade amigo, mas a ideia é ele editar a função e adaptar a realidade dele. Vou editar, em todo caso